# CRC (cyclic redundancy check) error while installing windows on a computer without any OS

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I think my internal hard drive has a problem

My computer does not have any OS installed so I was going to install a windows on my computer and when I tried creating a new partition I encountered an error 0x80070017 which stated "Cannot create a partition", then I tried Command Line with Diskpart and I wanted to create a partition primary with it which I encountered that CRC error!

Comment: Put the drive in a computer that has an OS and run a disk check.  If you have a computer that already has windows, the tool would be chkdsk.

Comment: so you mean I have to open up my computer and connect my hard drive to another device?

Comment: You don't *have* to.  You could also boot to windows via USB instead.

Comment: Sounds like that HDD is bad. Is it still under warranty? Some manufacturers will tell you to run their special tool that will tell if the drive is bad.

Comment: no the warranty has ended! and you're right, it's bad sectors

Answer (score 0):

In this case the error 0x80070017 means that the files that are being copied doesn't make it to the hard drive in the same way. This could mean your media (the one you got Windows installation) could be corrupted or the hard drive could be bad (bad sectors, etc).

So what you could do is remake a Windows installation. use a USB in this case. Try that first and reinstall it. If it makes the same error again then we can assume your usb stick is fine since you just made with without any problems.

At this point, use another hard drive since the one your using could be bad. As others stated in the comment section, you may want to remove it and install it on another computer and use the "chkdsk" command (chkdsk [drive] /f /r or use the Windows usb installation and boot on it and do that command from your usb stick.

Comment: I tried everything you said !!
even check disk , when I wanted to run check disk , the error "failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 50" showed up.
I think my hard drive is having bad sectors !!

Comment: yup, replace the drive. its dead or near death. try to copy the data from it as much as you can and replace it. Copying the data from a defective hard drive can be troublesome to near impossible... but thats a whole new subject

Comment: I'm running a check for bad sectors and seeing if there's a slight chance for recovering the sectors with HDD Regenerator! do you think it'll recover?

Comment: possibly. at this point I'd like to say you got a 50/50 chance to recover. Just on top of my head there spinrite which could help you with this. Theres also hhd regen that can help you with that: either grc.com or http://www.dposoft.net/hdd.html